# Do form fields who have the same background color than the page break any accessiblity rules?

Tags: accessibility, section508

I have a simple page that has form fields. 
Both the form fields and the page have a white background color (Browser default).
Will this cause an issue for visually impair users as they will probably have a hard time locating the form fields visually?

Comment: Does the input have a border?

Comment: As you used the tag [tag:section508], do you exclusively look for what section 508 says about it?

Comment: Yes, the input has the following border: `border: 1px solid #C4C4C4`

Comment: Yes, I'm also looking for what section 508 says about this.
Although, being 506 compliant, doesn't really mean being accessible.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to 508, it is fine, unless you are throwing `border:none` on it. Assistive technology (used by people with disabilities) grabs whatever `<label>` is associated with it:

```
<label for="someID">Your Name</label> <input type="text" id="someID">
```

If you want to be fancy,  you could do:

```
input:focus { outline-color: #006; outline-offset: 3px; outline-width:2px; }
```

Comment: AT includes more than screen readers (screen magnifiers for instance) and not all users of AT navigate with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility or 508 compliance is dependent on multiple things about how the field is rendered or altered.

- Some visually impaired users may be using screen reader in which case the background color would not matter as much but the "label" tag and other accessibility attributes will be of paramount importance.
- If you haven't applied any specific CSS to change the background color then the browser would render it in its native UI theme which typically is accessible. A lot of visually impaired user who do not have screen reader either use screen magnifier or use high contrast scheme so it should not be a problem.

In short if you have "label" tag applied appropriately and have not largely fiddled with the colors of the form field (i.e. left up to the browser to render it), you should have 508 compliant form.